# Reading byte value 26 in SerialPort vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have an vb.net winforms application that reads/writes serial data to several devices connected to a USB-RS485 device. The application is written in visual basic .NET 2008, altough i tried .NET 2015 as well.

Almost everything is working well except when one of the devices sends a message with a byte value of 26. Then im not sure what exactly happens but after the byte value of 26 the reading seems to stop. And all data after that is read in the next DataReceived event.

I have made a short program to only test the serialport. And it shows exactly the same. Also i have only one device connected with the test.
The data the device is sending consists of 10 bytes. The values are 251,20,(6 data bytes),checksum lo, checksum hi.

The first two and last two bytes can never reach a value of 26, it is just the data bytes that can do that.

Imports:

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Text
```

Variables:

```
Dim WithEvents SP_TestCom As SerialPort
Public DataArray() As Byte
```

subs:

```
Public Sub OpenCom()
    If SP_TestCom.IsOpen Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    SP_TestCom.Open()
End Sub

Public Sub CloseCom()
    If Not SP_TestCom.IsOpen Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    SP_TestCom.Close()
End Sub

Public Sub SendData(ByVal Data() As Byte)
    Try
        If SP_TestCom.IsOpen Then
            SP_TestCom.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub SP_TestCom_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SP_TestCom.DataReceived
    Try
        If SP_TestCom.BytesToRead > 0 Then
            Dim DataArray_Temp(SP_TestCom.BytesToRead + 1) As Byte
            SP_TestCom.Read(DataArray_Temp, 0, SP_TestCom.BytesToRead)

            Array.Copy(DataArray_Temp, DataArray, DataArray_Temp.Length)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

I have a main form with two buttons and a timer. The buttons are for opening and closing the port. The timer reads the dataarray

I have tried several ways of reading.

- Reading directly into an array
- Reading each byte seperatly
- Reading into a string and then converting it into a byte array

I also tried different encodings. Although i am not sure if it would have any effect.

- ASCII
- UNICODE
- UTF

All gives the same error.

I could bypass the error by ignoring any message containing a byte value of 26. This at least does not give me strange results in the rest of my application but it is not the perfect solution.

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue might be?

Edit:

```
Public Sub InitSerial()
    SP_TestCom = New SerialPort
    SP_TestCom.PortName = "COM26"
    SP_TestCom.ReadTimeout = 20
    SP_TestCom.BaudRate = 19200
    SP_TestCom.DataBits = 8
    SP_TestCom.StopBits = StopBits.One
    SP_TestCom.Parity = Parity.None
    SP_TestCom.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 10
End Sub
```

Comment: 26 is a magic value.  It is Ctrl+Z, the end-of-file character.  It makes your DataReceived event fire one extra time, this time with e.EventType = SerialData.Eof.  Pretty useful, helps you to diagnose the bugs in your code.  There isn't any way that Array.Copy() statement can be correct.

Comment: Ah i think i understand. I did not think of 26 making the datareceived event fire again. I will see if i can catch that so i read all data without problems.

Comment: For the Array.Copy(), it copies the source array which is DataArray_Temp to the actual array which is DataArray. The latter i read from my main form with the help of a timer. It does work but that not always means it is correct. Could you point out what is not correct?

Comment: The value of BytesToRead is completely unpredictable.  Tends to be 1 or 2, can be many.  Can be 0 in the case of Eof.  You must collect the received bytes until you have a full response, only then do you process it.  What that takes depends on the protocol that the device uses.  If it always sends 10 bytes then all you have to do is count them.

Comment: Ah i see. yeah i understand what you are saying, however (and this is something i forgot to add) during the creating of the serialport i set the ReceivedBytesThreshold to 10. Would that make the BytesToRead still unpredicatable?

Comment: Sigh.  It is then absolutely crucial to pay attention to e.EventType.   It will then be 10 but you have no real guarantee which 10.  Could be 4 from the previous and 6 from the next packet for example.  Synchronizing is important, you cannot do that correctly when you use ReceivedBytesThreshold.  Or it is not important if you have some sort of guarantee that the device is always turned on after your program starts.  Not very common.

Comment: I think i'm starting to understand it. I believe i have much to learn still about serial communications. I will work on improving my code with the help of your comments. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   SP_TestCom.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 10
```

That is a fairly troublesome property.  Yes, 26 is a magic number.  It is Ctrl+Z, the default end-of-file character.  Dates back to the stone age, unfortunately it cannot be changed.

It matters to your DataReceived event handler, it will fire one extra time to tell you about Eof.  That screws up your logic, the value of BytesToRead is unpredictable.  You have to get out quickly, like this:

```
Private Sub SP_TestCom_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SP_TestCom.DataReceived
    If e.EventType <> SerialData.Chars Then Return
    '' etc...
End Sub
```

---

Not the only problem with that property.  You now have a guarantee that ReceivedBytes will be *at least* 10.  Make sure you actually pass 10 to the Read() method.  But you don't know which 10 you'll get.  It could for example be 4 bytes of the previous packet and 6 bytes of the next.  That is not going to work well unless you very carefully control the start-up order.  The device must be turned on *after* your program starts up so you have a hard guarantee that the first byte you receive is the first byte of a packet.  Could work if you must send an explicit command to the device to start sending.

Or you may need to detect the start of a packet by a special byte value, like 251 in your case.  You then synchronize by reading single bytes, throwing ones away until you get 251.  You can't do that with ReceivedBytesThreshold > 1.

Also very, very important to use the ErrorReceived event.  Overrun errors happen, especially when there is no handshaking, you must re-synchronize when they occur.

You also need to pay attention to how you process the packet.  If you cannot do so in the DataReceived event handler then you need a thread-safe queue to ensure no data is lost.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589000/how-to-know-on-which-serial-port-external-device-is-connected-and-read-data-from