# How to know on which serial port external device is connected and read data from that device?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port

I have attached 1 device which generated some random number and i want to read that number through my **Windows application**.

I am using this code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM19");

    mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
    mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
    mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
    mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

    mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

    mySerialPort.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
    mySerialPort.Close();
}

private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    Debug.Print("Data Received:");
    Debug.Print(indata);
}
```

With this code I am successfully getting data.

But problem here is I have hardcoded my `com port(Com19)` that is from device manager I have checked that to which port my device is connected so I have hardcoded that but I don't want to do this.

Instead I will give user `1 dropdown` in which user will see only that port to which user device is connected. So when fetching data from this connected device I will use that user selected dropdown port.

I am very much new to windows application and never done anything related to serial port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have arduino connected to com port. I have use this code (assuming that arduino returned text with "Info from Arduino" inside):

```
SerialPort currentPort; // global variables
bool ArduinoPortFound = false;
```

...

```
        try
        {
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                currentPort = new SerialPort(port, 9600);
                if (ArduinoDetected())
                {
                    ArduinoPortFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ArduinoPortFound = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
```

......

```
        private bool ArduinoDetected()
    {
        try
        {
            currentPort.Open();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); 

            string returnMessage = currentPort.ReadLine();
            currentPort.Close();

            if (returnMessage.Contains("Info from Arduino"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
Or you can also use [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx?tduid=%2872f7186e7d981c843834278c421d9d39%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-R2o6CvZ8dzRPHorLTVVykw%29%28%29)

Here is article about it:
[How to programmatically find a COM port by friendly name](https://dariosantarelli.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/c-how-to-programmatically-find-a-com-port-by-friendly-name/)

Comment: Getting Error on this line:  currentPort = new SerialPort(port, 9600);//An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.I have placed this code in static void main

Comment: Nothing happens on this line: string returnMessage = currentPort.ReadLine();

Comment: add "static" to variables and ArduinoDetected method if you have console application

Comment: if port doesn't returns new line you can try string returnMessage = currentPort.ReadExisting();

Comment: Error:Access to the port 'COM19' is denied on this line:currentPort.Open();

Comment: Ok got it working because i was having one software called TeraTerm which was reading data from that device that is why i got this error i guess.Am i right??

Comment: yes. seems that port was busy. occupied by other application

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem like though i have this software teraterm reading data from this device but still i can read this device data from my console application??

Comment: you can handle the exception in catch block. so you can see in exception that port is opened already by another software and can try to wait and try to open it once again later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109002/discussion-between-learning-and-alexej-sommer).

Comment: here is [code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71629f75f64b14923a1110f13c63c2d1) to check is port busy

Comment: Thanks you so much for your kind help.it really helped me and keep helping like this.....

Answer (score 1):

```
ManagementObjectCollection mReturn;
ManagementObjectSearcher mSearch;
mSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_SerialPort");
mReturn = mSearch.Get();

Combobox cboPort = new Combobox();

foreach (ManagementObject mObj in mReturn)
{
   cboPort.Items.Add(mObj["Name"].ToString());
}
```

Modify your code as follows

```
SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(cboPort.Text);
```

I hope this will help you, and do modification according to your requirement.